# error: cannot find symbol method get Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to update the SQLite in MainActivity with another Java class.
I am using Intent but I have this error.
When I searched, I realized that with OnCreate I can take intent but I have a simple Java Class.

In My MainActivity I send it this way which does not seem like any problem here:

```
        btnupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Calisan calisan = new Calisan();



            if (Util.editTextControl(txtFirstNameUpdate_New)) {

                if (Util.editTextControl(txtFirstNameUpdate_New)) {

                    calisan.setAd(txtFirstNameUpdate_New.getText().toString());
                    calisan.setSoyad(txtLastNameUpdate_New.getText().toString());

                } else {

                    Util.showMessage(MainActivity.this, "Yeni Soyisim Alanı Boş Bırakılamaz.");
                }
            } else {

                Util.showMessage(MainActivity.this, "Yeni İsim Alanı Boş Bırakılamaz.");
            }



            Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, DBContext.class );

            intent.putExtra("ID", txtUpdatedID.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra ( "FirstNameUpdate", txtFirstNameUpdate_New.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("LastNameUpdate", txtLastNameUpdate_New.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);

            boolean sonuc = DBContext.getInstance(MainActivity.this).updateEmployees(calisan.getId(), calisan.getAd(), calisan.getSoyad());

             Util.showMessage(MainActivity.this, sonuc ? "Calisan Eklendi" : "Calısan Eklenemedi");




        }
    });
```

And in the second Activity:

```
public final class DBContext {



    public boolean updateEmployees(long guncellenicekID, String guncellenecekAd, String guncellenicekSoyad){

        boolean result = false;

        //This is where I get error: cannot find symbol method 
        //getIntent()   

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String updatedFirstName = i.getStringExtra("FirstNameUpdate");
        String updatedLastName = i.getStringExtra("LastNameUpdate");
        int ID = i.getIntExtra("ID",0);



        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
        cvUpdate.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME, updatedFirstName);
        cvUpdate.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_LAST_NAME, updatedLastName);

        long id = database.update(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, cvUpdate, DBHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + guncellenicekID, null);

        if (id != -1){

            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Thanks !

Comment: why do you need intent?

Comment: Your `DBContext` class is not an `Activity`, so it doesn't have methods like `getIntent()` that are a part of `Activity`

Comment: try to import it by hand like `import android.content.intent`

Answer (score 1):

This is because your are trying to get the intent() with DBContext which is not an Activity or not a subclass of activity. Please read about [getIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()).

You need to make your method accepting the Intent as parameter like this:

```
public final class DBContext {
  ...

  public boolean updateEmployees(long guncellenicekID, String guncellenecekAd, String guncellenicekSoyad, Intent intent){
    ...
  }
}
```

But you **should not** using the above code. You should not make your `DBContext` aware of Intent existences. You should make DbContext doing its work, which is Database operation, and ignoring everything unrelated to it.

You can change your method to something like this:

```
public final class DBContext {
  ...

  // pass all the data via the parameters.
  public boolean updateEmployees(long guncellenicekID, String guncellenecekAd, String guncellenicekSoyad, String updatedFirstName, String updatedLastName, int id){
    ...
  }
}
```

though it looks messy.

You can also make all the parameters as pojo, then pass it as `updateEmployees` parameter. First, create the pojo:

```
// Pojo
public class Employee {
  String guncellenicekID;
  String guncellenecekAd;
  String guncellenicekSoyad;
  String updatedFirstName; 
  String updatedLastName;
  int id;

  // Constructor
  // setter, you need to create it.
  // getter, you need to create it. 
}
```

DbContext:

```
public final class DBContext {
  ...

  // pass all the data via the parameters.
  public boolean updateEmployees(Employee employee){
    ...

    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME, employee.getUpdatedFirstName());
    cvUpdate.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_LAST_NAME, employee.getUpdatedLastName());

    long id = database.update(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, cvUpdate, DBHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + employee.getGuncellenicekID(), null);

     ...
  }
}
```

Then you can call the method with something like this:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setUpdatedFirstName("sampleFirstName");
employee.setUpdatedLastName("sampleLastName");
// set the other data
...

DbContext.getInstance().updateEmployees(employee);
```